# Intent from notification isn't passed to target activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have starting activity which starts/restore app's activities and pass to it all intent extras if there are any:
manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Code:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preloader);
        String id=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        Log.d("push~","start activity oncreate:"+id);
        Intent i = new Intent(getIntent());
        openLastActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String id=intent.getStringExtra("id");
        Log.d("push~","start activity new intent:"+id);
        openLastActivity(intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    private void openLastActivity(Intent i){
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        if(GameActivity._this!=null) {
            i.setClass(this,GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            i.setClass(this,SelectorActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also my app has service which generates notifications with following content intent:

```
Intent notificationIntent= new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("id",id);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

I expect id string will be passed to the last active activity.
The problem is when I run the app via notification tap it starts app and pass id as expected but if there is another notification(when I'm still in the app) neither onCreate nor onNewIntent method of the `StartActivity` is called therefore no data are passed to main activities.

UPD:Don't know why but `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for `StartActivity` solved my problem.Now all intents are receiving in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for `StartActivity` solved my problem.Now all intents are receiving in `onCreate`